# Clarificaiton of base case needed with mergeSort

Tags: mergesort

I know this is a very simple question, but I'm learning on my own, so please bear with me!

In Wikipedia's psuedocode of [mergeSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) (see below), the terminal case is if the length of the array / list is less than or equal to one. In the comments, they say if it's length of 0 or 1, then it's sorted. This I agree with, but I'm curious does this mean that mergeSort won't work if the code had `if (length == 1)`? I'm just confused how an array could possibly split to a 0 length array. Wouldn't it stop already if it's length was equal to 1?

```
function merge_sort(list m)
    // Base case. A list of zero or one elements is sorted, by definition.
    if length of m ≤ 1 then
        return m

    // Recursive case. First, divide the list into equal-sized sublists
    // consisting of the even and odd-indexed elements.
    var left := empty list
    var right := empty list
    for each x with index i in m do
        if i is odd then
            add x to left
        else
            add x to right

    // Recursively sort both sublists.
    left := merge_sort(left)
    right := merge_sort(right)

    // Then merge the now-sorted sublists.
    return merge(left, right)
```

Comment: Dear OP, you're asking a lot of questions lately without accepting answers, even though there are acceptable answers. Please reward the people who have helped you and accept answers to your questions. Thanks.

Comment: @DarkDust Thanks, I've done so, but not all of them have supplied the answer I am / was looking for. Sometimes, they're answered in the comments, and I upvote those comments (thought I know that does nothing as far as reputation goes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is recursive, which means the function is splitting the list and then calls itself with each part. To terminate the recursion, `if (length == 1)` would be sufficient as there would never be an empty list as result of the splitting. You got this right.

But the *user* can call this function with an empty list. So that needs to be caught as well. Hence the `if (length <= 1)` (`if length of m ≤ 1 then return m`).